# how to use perl script for multiple file

Tags: windows, perl, cmd

Hi i am using perl on windows for this script id3clean.pl which has input file argument as .mp3

```
perl -w id3clean.pl 1.mp3
```

but what is the command so that script will be run for all mp3 file in folder please help

Comment: In Perl, you have to alter your code to support multiple files. In windows batch script, I suppose you could manage some loop that allows multiple arguments, or wildcards. It is quite hard to say how to edit your file without knowing what the code looks like.

Comment: thanks for help can u please give example of windows batch script specific for my command

Comment: Not really. I am a Perl programmer, I don't know much about batch script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Windows command, if you prefer not to edit Perl code, you could do it by calling your Perl script for each MP3 file using a FOR LOOP like this:

```
for %f in (*.mp3) do perl -w id3clean.pl "%f"
```

In Linux, you could do it quite the same way in a Bash shell:

```
for f in *.mp3; do perl -w id3clean.pl "$f"; done
```

Comment: That has the downside of having to call/execute the perl script multiple times (once for each file) instead of executing it once and have it process the multiple mp3 files.

Comment: That has the advantage of leaving the original Perl script intact. However, @RonBergin solution may lead to higher performance if the file list is huge.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line near the beginning of your perl script.

```
BEGIN { @ARGV = map{ glob } @ARGV }
```

Then call your script like this.

```
perl id3clean.pl *.mp3
```

The list of files will then be found in the @ARGV array.

Comment: Why the down vote?  The OP's question can be interpreted in 2 ways.  1) modify the perl script or 2) write a batch script wrapper.  They both have their advantages and disadvantages.  Adjusting the perl script to work with multiple files is more efficient than the batch script wrapper.

Comment: You've explained only a tiny part of the required changes to the Perl script, and it should be `@ARGV = map { glob qq{"$_"} } @ARGV`